# Howto: gitlab pipeline external buildserver stage order

Tags: teamcity, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to change the pipeline stage order in gitlab for external buildserver

Is there any option to configure a external buildserver, in my case Teamcity, configured as "Commit status publisher" build feature, to run before the default gitlab ci stages?

At the moment, the gitlab deploy job, configured in `gitlab-ci.yml`, will be executed before the teamcity build response.

I need to run the deploy job after the teamcity build.